# How to create an Error Log using log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, appender

how would I go about creating an Error Log that only writes to a file if something is logged with a level of ERROR and above and how would I also print all logs to the console in eclipse?

Will I need two appenders? Right now, my appender always makes a new file even if the log is of type INFO and not ERROR.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Error -->
    <appender name="ErrorFile"
         class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="error"/>
        <param name="file" value="./logs/error_report_${file.date.format}.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%p] [%c{1}]: %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="error"/> 
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
        </filter>     
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/> 
    </appender>

    <!-- Console -->
    <appender name="Console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] [%c{1}]: %m%n" />
        </layout>

    </appender>


    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorFile"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: The Threshold option blocks out all levels below ERROR but the file is still created, only with nothing in it. I only want the file to be created if an error is logged.

Comment: Please add your log configuration.

Comment: This is my code from a previous post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886596/log4j-file-is-created-every-time-i-run-my-program-but-i-only-want-it-to-creat/33886911